# I want to convert a string to a char using strcpy_s, but it gives a size error

Tags: c++, string, strcpy

I'm trying to use strcpy_s, but i get another error dealing with the size,  saying : `L "Buffer is too small && 0"` when i try to run the program, and i dont know if`sizeof tochar` from `strcpy_s(tochar, sizeof tochar, test.c_str());`  is correct because I keep getting this error.

**Full compiling code:**

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <sstream>  
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;
    using std::vector;
    using std::string;

    int main()
    {


        std::string test;
        std::vector<std::string> v3 = { "filename1", "filename2","filename3", };
        for (int m = 0; m < v3.size(); m++) {
        test = "\"" + v3[m] + ".txt" + "\"";
            char * tochar = new char[test.length() + 1];
            strcpy_s(tochar, sizeof tochar, test.c_str());
            std::cout << tochar << std::endl;

        }
return 0;
    }
```

I cant use `strcpy` in c++ 2015, i have to use `strcpy_s` now because `strcpy` gives a different error, and i dont want to just turn off the error. (unless there is some sort of code i can put in the program that will let it compile with `strcpy`)

I want the `tochar` to output: "filename1.txt"

Comment: Your second parameter to strcpy_s is wrong.

Comment: Thats what i figured, so thats why i posted.

Comment: It is the length of the `tochar` buffer, not the pointer.  What you want to pass there is the allocated length of the buffer (`test.length() + 1`).

Comment: Oh okay,  because in the example of `strcpy_s` from cppreference, it uses `sizeof tochar`

Comment: Because in that example tochar is a static array (`char tochar[16]`).

Answer (score 1):

The second copy to strcpy_s should be the number of characters you wish to copy.

```
strcpy_s(tochar, test.length() + 1, test.c_str());
```

would be one way to write it, I think.

```
sizeof tochar
```

is giving you the size of the char pointer variable, not the size of the array you've allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this strcpy_s(tochar, sizeof tochar, test.c_str()); you need to do
strcpy_s(tochar, test.length() + 1, test.c_str());

When you say sizeof tochar, you are having value 4 or 8 as it is an pointer.
But for the api, you need to tell the size of destination array

Answer (score 0):

to use strcpy
try dont use

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

use

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and use of `strcpy` is deprecated because it is unsafe due to the potential for buffer overrun.

Comment: @Aracthor do not tag incorrect answers as low quality.